# footer white space and dont stick below

Tags: html, css

why my footer css wont take the full Edge with 100% ?? there is a white space on left. how do i fix this ?? before when i use 100% width , the footer take full 100% but now it have white space every time i use footer. can any one tell me why?

the footer also wont stick to below. i always need to use position to fix it.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        footer{
            width:100%;
            height:50px;
            background-color:blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<footer>
    i am footer.
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/stbr5wt6/

Comment: i have no idea what i did wrong , is a simple code but i i feel like it have so much bug at footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body has a default 8px margin so you need to remove that.

```
body {
     margin: 0;
}
```

That should remove that space.  You'll probably want to add some padding to your footer as well or your footer content will run right to the edge of the screen.

For the positioning of the footer...you'll need to put some content above it so it pushes down, or apply absolute positioning to fix it to the bottom, or add a 'min-height' declaration on the content area so it has height regardless of whether there is content or not.

Answer (score 0):

body and other elements have margin by default

use

```
 body{margin:0;}
```

how will footer go down if you dont have any content above it?

use absolute position that will work in your case

```
footer{
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     background-color:red;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
  }
```

Comment: but isit footer always stay at the page below ?? before i never use any position css and everything work fine , but why isit happening now ?